# How do I remove the unity 2D option in lightdm (login sceen) in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: lightdm, unity-2d, login-screen, username, fonts

Because I wish to view my full username at login, I want to remove the "Unity 2D" option at the login screen. Currently the last part of the username (after the 20th digit) is hidden behind the Ubuntu-icon which enables switching to Unity 2D.

Another option would be to decrease the font-size of the username, is any of this possible?

Btw this is not an issue in Ubuntu 12.10, where the username font-size is smaller, and Unity 2D unsupported!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot shrink the font in the user box without a re-compile of the greeter unfortunately. If you don't ever want to use Unity-2d, you can simply rename the ubuntu-2d desktop file.  I don't have a 12.04 system handy, but I think the file is ubuntu-2d.desktop, it lives in /usr/share/xsessions:

```
sudo mv /usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu-2d.desktop /usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu-2d.desktop.OLD
```

After you do that you need to reboot or restart lightdm from a virtual terminal. Here's one thing to note, in 12.10, the session chooser is hidden if there's only one session, I'm not sure that's true in 12.04, but try it and let me know and I can edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The session chooser is still present (but shows only one item) in 12.04 if the /usr/share/xsessions directory contains only one .desktop entry.